# Strange behaviour of overridden Style of TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, textblock

Some days ago I've faced with strange behaviour of text inside Button (I guess the same behaviour I would got for other ContentControls). Let me explain the situation. I have a style definition in App.xaml for TextBlock:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

In MainWindow.xaml I have the same style definition, that should override style that defined in App.xaml. Also I have 3 buttons in Window. In first button explicitly defined TextBlock control inside button's content. For second button I set a string as content in codebehind. For third button I set an integer value as content in codebehind. Here is code of MainWindow.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Name="Button1">
        <Button.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="Button with text block"/>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
    <Button Name="Button2" />
    <Button Name="Button3" />
</StackPanel>
```

and MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button2.Content = "Button with string";
    Button3.Content = 16;
}
```

And now what we see? Text in first and third buttons, as expected, have margins 0px, but text in second button have margins 10px! The question is: why second button has 10px margins and how set zero margins for second button (removing style from App.xaml is not possible)?

Thank you!

Comment: What does [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) reveal?

Comment: I have tried your code: Snoop says that second TextBlock has Margin=10 whereas the other TextBlocks have Margin=0. The value source is a style in all three cases. Currently, I have no idea what causes the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I change

```
Button2.Content = "Button with string";
```

to

```
Button2.Content = "Button with _string";
```

the button's margin changes from 10 to 0.

This is a bug in WPF; it already has been reported on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/435093/textblock-style-applies-to-button-when-content-has-access-key-defined).

I am not 100% sure but I think the behavior you saw is caused by the same root cause.

By the way: the correct behavior would be that buttons 2 and 3 have Margin=10; this is because resource lookup is performed along the logical tree, not along the visual tree. The TextBlocks in the buttons 2 and 3 are not inside the logical tree of the StackPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a definitive answer, but I notice that it's the difference between setting a string and an integer which causes the different styles to be applied.

Since setting Content to a value that requires a conversion results in correct style being applied, I tried this:

```
private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button2.Content = new TextHolder("Button with string");
    Button3.Content = 16;
}

public class TextHolder
{
    private readonly string _text;

    public TextHolder(string text)
    {
        _text = text;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _text;
    }
}
```

and the margin is now 0.  I would be interested in understanding exactly what is going on.